# oracle deadlock parent/child and child has indexed FK

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, deadlock, indexed

I need somebody  help me to figure out the cause of following deadlock.
the involved tables are parent/child and child table has indexed FK.
 parent:PK_FMS_FC_MAIN_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT
 chile:FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT

```
Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-0019000b-0000b486        22    2755     X             57     492           S
TX-00010019-00061e13        57     492     X             22    2755           S

session 2755: DID 0001-0016-00000FCE    session 492: DID 0001-0039-00000719 
session 492: DID 0001-0039-00000719 session 2755: DID 0001-0016-00000FCE 

Rows waited on:
  Session 2755: obj - rowid = 000DB256 - AADbJWABbAAAYJQAAA
  (dictionary objn - 897622, file - 91, block - 98896, slot - 0)
  Session 492: no row

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
Session 492:
  sid: 492 ser: 2757 audsid: 132281277 user: 364/GKS_IM_9990740
    flags: (0x41) USR/- flags_idl: (0x1) BSY/-/-/-/-/-
    flags2: (0x40009) -/-/INC
  pid: 57 O/S info: user: grid, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 16372
    image: oracle@hgksdb01
  client details:
    O/S info: user: imart, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
    machine: hgkswa05 program: JDBC Thin Client
    application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
  current SQL:
  DELETE FROM FMS_FC_MAIN_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT MAIN WHERE MAIN.ID = :B1 

----- End of information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

Information for THIS session:

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=56azrvwd48huf) -----
INSERT INTO FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT( ID, RELATION_FIELD_MASTER_CD, CREATE_USER_CD, CREATE_DATE, RECORD_USER_CD, RECORD_DATE ) VALUES( :B4 , :B3 , :B2 , SYSDATE, :B1 , SYSDATE )
----- PL/SQL Stack -----
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x1f37f7a58       462  package body GKS_IM_9990740.ZPKG_PRJ_FLDREL
0x1ed1a9d38         1  anonymous block
===================================================

CREATE TABLE GKS_IM_9990740.FMS_FC_MAIN_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT
(
ID                             NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL,
COMPANY_CD                     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
MAIN_FIELD_TYPE                VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
RELATION_FIELD_TYPE            VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
START_DATE                     DATE NOT NULL,
MAIN_FIELD_MASTER_CD           VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL,
MAIN_FIELD_SUB_CD              VARCHAR2(1000),
IS_INPUT_ENABLE                VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
IS_INPUT_COMPULSORY            VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
DEFAULT_VALUE                  VARCHAR2(1000),
IS_INPUT_LIMIT                 VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
CREATE_USER_CD                 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
CREATE_DATE                    TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
RECORD_USER_CD                 VARCHAR2(100),
RECORD_DATE                    TIMESTAMP(6),
CONSTRAINT PK_FMS_FC_MAIN_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
MAXTRANS 255
TABLESPACE FMS_DATA
STORAGE(INITIAL 64K NEXT 1M MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
LOGGING
)

CREATE TABLE GKS_IM_9990740.FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT
(
ID                             NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL,
RELATION_FIELD_MASTER_CD       VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL,
CREATE_USER_CD                 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
CREATE_DATE                    TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
RECORD_USER_CD                 VARCHAR2(100),
RECORD_DATE                    TIMESTAMP(6),
CONSTRAINT PK_FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT PRIMARY KEY (ID, RELATION_FIELD_MASTER_CD) USING INDEX
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 2
MAXTRANS 255
TABLESPACE FMS_DATA
STORAGE(INITIAL 64K NEXT 1M MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
LOGGING,
CONSTRAINT FK_FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT0 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES GKS_IM_9990740.FMS_FC_MAIN_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT (ID)
)
PCTFREE 10
MAXTRANS 255
TABLESPACE FMS_DATA
STORAGE(INITIAL 64K NEXT 1M MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
NOCACHE
LOGGING

CREATE INDEX "GKS_IM_9990740"."FK_FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT" ON "GKS_IM_9990740"."FMS_FC_REL_FLD_INPUT_LIMIT"
(
"ID"
)
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS STORAGE
(
INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
)
TABLESPACE "FMS_DATA" ;
```

Comment: a couple of ideas if possible: 1) can you simplify the example as much as possible and recreate the dead lock.  2) it appears a delete is being done on the parent table with inserts being done on the child table this will cause issues.  however because the values of the bind variables are not know it is hard to determine. 3)I have run into deadlock issues using bit mapped indexes.  Is the FK index the only one other than the Unique Indexes for the primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:
1.)  Since the enqueues involved in the deadlock are TX, and not TM, this has *nothing* to do with the unindexed foreign key problem.
2.)  Since the sessions are waiting on TX 'S' (shared) mode, this is *not* a row-level locking problem.
3.)  Since one of the statements involved is an INSERT, that one is not going to be a problem with ITL slot shortage.

So, given the above, my best guesses are:
For the delete, bitmap index or ITL slot shortage.
for the insert, overlapping pk/uk.

Hope that helps....